# Tableview Cell dynamic height with images

Tags: ios, uitableview, xamarin, cell

I have a tableview that takes full width & height of my current controller. Each cell contains only an image, taking the full width of the tableview.

What I don't know is the size of the image, that I need to not be cropped or stretched.

What I need is my cell to resize itself depending on the image it's holding. The image is loaded using SDWebImage from the internet after the cell is created.

I've seen many ridiculous answers everywhere about hardcoding values or anything else you could imagine following the same thought process, but that is out of question here.

I've tried using

```
tableview.RowHeight = UITablevies.DynamicDimension;
tableview.EstimatedRowHeight = aFloatValue;
```

But that just does not work as expected.

When the cells are loaded, their heights are matching the image, but the image does not fill the full width. So it's not good because there is a gap on the side.

Then after scrolling away then rescrolling back to that cell, they resize abruptly (and it's visually not acceptable) to take the full width like they should but the cell resizes itself way too far in terms of height, and at that point there is a gap between the cells.

So this solution has two problems : cell resize themselves for some reason, too late, and before AND after each resize, there is a size problem.

See attached images for clarity.

Too small, gap on the sides
[image: Here cells are too small]

Too big, gap above and under.
[image: Here cells are too big]

The resize happens when the cell is reloaded, and pushes the whole tableview down, which makes a very sudden and abrupt move for all the iamges and is not acceptable.

Édit :
- I can not ask for the image size where I get the image.
- Constraints are top bottom leading and trailing with superview's borders at 0
- The image is already way larger than the cell, it's sized down for sure.
- The image is supposed to take the full width, and I want the Height of the cell to be exactly the Height of the image. The height of the image is whatever number it is when the image keeps its aspect ratio when taking full width

Comment: How do you get the image URLs? You should manage a way to have also the aspect ratio of the images with the URLs. So before even loading the image from the net you have the cell already sized correctly.

Comment: You said "image that I need to not be cropped or stretched" If picture sizes are preserved you WILL get gaps. Is it suppose to be full width? Then it has to be stretched. If not then you will get gaps. Can you show the picture of what ideally you want to get?

Comment: Have you tried to set HasUnevenRows ?

Comment: You can't achieve that unless your image has at least the same width with your device. If it's larger, then no problem, you can down size, but if it's narrower, then you'll get gaps

Comment: Also, show us the layout constraints you have used in your cell

Comment: Answered all your questions in an update down the bottom. Any other question ? :)